# How do I display this information from the local storage on a different page

Tags: javascript

This is supposed to be a reminder app which has an input page to put the task and some information in and an output page which is supposed to contain all the things on the checklist.
What do I need to add to make the information go to the output page?
This is the code that stores the items locally and the html

```
<form id="todoForm">
  <label for="ReminderInput">Reminder</label>
  <input class="u-full-width" type="text" id="ReminderInput">


  <label for="DateInput">Date</label>
  <input class="u-full-width" type="datetime-local" id="DateInput">


  <label for="InfoInput">Additional Information</label>
  <textarea class="u-full-width" type="text" placeholder="Remember to..."
            id="InfoInput"></textarea>
  <button type="button" id="btn" class="button-primary">Add Reminder</button>
</form>
```

```js
let reminders = [];

const addReminders = (ev) => {
  ev.preventDefault();
  let reminder = {
    ReminderInput: document.getElementById("ReminderInput").value,
    DateInput: document.getElementById("DateInput").value,
    InfoInput: document.getElementById("InfoInput").value,
  };

  const arr = [reminder.ReminderInput, reminder.DateInput, reminder.InfoInput];

  localStorage.setItem("todoForm", JSON.stringify(arr));
  reminders.push([
    reminder.ReminderInput,
    reminder.DateInput,
    reminder.InfoInput,
  ]);
  localStorage.setItem("reminders", JSON.stringify(reminders));
};

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", addReminders);
});
```

Comment: Why not use [`localStorage.getItem()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/getItem)?

Answer (score 1):

Use sessionStorage instead of localStorage

> localStorage and sessionStorage accomplish the exact same thing and
>   have the same API, but with sessionStorage the data is persisted only
>   until the window or tab is closed

```
sessionStorage.setItem('todoForm', JSON.stringify(arr))
reminders.push([reminder.ReminderInput, reminder.DateInput, reminder.InfoInput]);
sessionStorage.setItem("reminders", JSON.stringify(reminders));
```

To get the keys above:

```
let todoForm = sessionStorage.getItem('todoForm');

let reminders = sessionStorage.getItem('reminders');

console.log(todoForm);
console.log(reminders);
```

Comment: where do I add this to my code and also I want to use local storage because I want to save all the reminders  even if he user closes the window

Comment: You use the code on the output page. `localStorage` is preserved across the website and can be accessed on any page.